# Angular Login Authentication: When submit button is pressed twice with invalid credentials, automatically login

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have created a simple login function in Angular with Spring Boot. Here are my Angular controllers. My backend function returns a boolean true or false and It returns correctly. The mystery is, the first click on the login button, for both correct and wrong credentials it goes to the else block in the autheticate() method (makes it a invalid login). But when again click on the login button (with any data for username n password), even though the response from the backend is "false" it goes inside the if block and authenticate the login. Can someone help me to tell why this happens and how to correct it? (is my logic here and code is correct?. Spent days now looking where is the error)

Login.component.html

```
<div class="content-header">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-top: 50px;">
            <form>
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                  <img src="assets/dist/img/logo.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" style="width: 218px;height: 218px;">
                </div>
                <div class="imgcontainer" *ngIf=message>
                    {{message}}
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                  <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" [(ngModel)]="authObjModel.username" name="uname" required>

                  <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" [(ngModel)]="authObjModel.password" name="psw" required>

                  <button type="button" (click)=checkLogin()>Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Login.component.ts

```
import { AuthService } from "./../auth.service";
import { AuthObj } from "./../auth-obj";
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;
  invalidLogin = false;
  authObjModel = new AuthObj("","");

  constructor(private loginservice:AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  checkLogin() {
    if (this.loginservice.authenticate(this.authObjModel)) {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      this.invalidLogin = false;
    } else {
    this.invalidLogin = true;
    this.message = 'Invalid Credentials';
    }
  }
}
```

Auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  status:any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authenticate(credentials) {
    const response = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', credentials, { responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
.subscribe((data) => this.status = data);
    if ( this.status ) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('username', credentials.username);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }    
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    return !(user === null);
  }

  logOut() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
  }
}
```